# Mysql - move and replace columns

Tags: mysql

We have two databases `A` and `B` and we want to move and replace some columns with all values from database `A` to database `B`

```
 Database.SourceTable >>> move to >>> Database.TargetTable
 A.User1              >>>         >>> B.User2
```

The user table has many columns, but we only want to replace some columns: `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

How can i do this?

Thank you

EDIT: I forget to say, that i only want to replace the first 100 columns id's.

I mean each column has more than 100 id's and i want to replace first 100; not all.

Comment: do they have the same number of rows and the same primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you're not able to move datas from a database to another one with a single connection**, you can't do it with a single query, you need to do it manually, or with a third party language.

You'll need to :

- get one connection per database
- get a `PRIMARY KEY` on your table `user`
- export datas from `databaseA`
- inject these datas to `databaseB`

Example with PHP/PDO :

```php
// Create 2 connections
try {
  $dbA = new PDO('mysql:dbname=databaseA;host=localhost', 'root', '');
  $dbB = new PDO('mysql:dbname=databaseB;host=localhost', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

// Get datas from databaseA
$result = $dbA->query("SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM user");

// Prepare REPLACE query for databaseB
$query = "REPLACE INTO user (id, col1, col2, col3) VALUES";
$values = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    array_push($values, '('.$row['id'].', "'.$row['col1'].'", "'.$row['col2'].'", "'.$row['col3'].'")');
}
$query .= implode(',', $values);

// Execute REPLACE query on databaseB
$stmt = $dbB->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank youu , it works , but now i have another question . i forgeted to say . I just want to Replace the first 100 columns id's . i means each cloumns have more than 100 id's and i want to replace first 100 . not all

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? What's your goal ? What are these ids ?

Comment: sure , i was joined two database users togeather but for first 100 users some values should be changed . i have right information in another database with same columns for first 100 users . so i want to replace that correct values to this database . but Only for first 100 Users , not for more than 100 id's . the id's saved in cloumns "userid" i need to move and replace col1 , col2 , col3 values  ONLY for first 100 userid's

Comment: So, if you want to select data for 100 firsts users : `SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100` (make sure this request retrieve what you want, before doing your REPLACE).

Answer (score 1):

If `table1` on `db1` database has `t1c1`, `t1c2`,`t1c3` columns and you want only `t1c1`, and `t1c3` data be copied into `table2` of database `db2` with columns `t2c1` and `t2c2` then

```
insert into db2.table2( t2c1, t2c2 ) select t1c1, t1c3 from db1.table1
```

should work for you.

And make sure that you have required privileges set to access data from cross database tables or other objects. And you should also check issues with constraints, if any defined, on `table2`.

Comment: thank you , it works when both of tables are available on same database .anyway thanks